# crosstab in php for codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

am using the following code

```
  Sample Gender Handedness
    1   Female  Right-handed
    2   Male    Left-handed
    3   Female  Right-handed
    4   Male    Right-handed
    5   Male    Left-handed
    6   Male    Right-handed
    7   Female  Right-handed
    8   Female  Left-handed
    9   Male    Right-handed
    10  Female  Right-handed
```

```
              Left-
             handed    Right-
                       handed Total
    Males   2   3   5
    Females 1   4   5
    Total   3   7   10
```

am having as above table and i need to get as the second table. i need to use crosstab but i was not known how to do that. can someone help me please. am doing this in codeigniter.

Comment: what is crosstab? also show us the relevant code/markup

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_tabulation please check this url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a query

```sql
SELECT gender,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Handedness = 'Left-handed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) left_handed,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Handedness = 'Right-handed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) right_handed,
       COUNT(*) total
  FROM Table1
 GROUP BY gender WITH ROLLUP
```

Output:

```
| GENDER | LEFT_HANDED | RIGHT_HANDED | TOTAL |
|--------|-------------|--------------|-------|
| Female |           1 |            4 |     5 |
|   Male |           2 |            3 |     5 |
| (null) |           3 |            7 |    10 | -- this is your total produced by WITH ROLLUP
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9806/4)** demo

---

I'm not an expert in CI but your code might look like

```php
$sql = "SELECT gender,
               SUM(CASE WHEN Handedness = 'Left-handed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) left_handed,
               SUM(CASE WHEN Handedness = 'Right-handed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) right_handed,
               COUNT(*) total
          FROM Table1
         GROUP BY gender WITH ROLLUP";
$data = $this->db->query($sql)->result_array();
```

Comment: Use raw query in CI. And then produce your markup in the view while iterating over the array with the resultset. Or you expecting one of us to write all the code for you?

Comment: no no not in that way as am new to codeigniter am asking a sample code for reference as need to do this in controller and model na so. hope you understand. thanks

Comment: one more doubt var numberArray=[5,5,1,1], thisTotal=0,thisMean=0;
// add elements of array together 
 for(var i=0;i<numberArray.length;i++)
  {thisTotal+=numberArray[i];}
// calculate average  
 thisMean=(thisTotal/numberArray.length);
 thisFrequency=(numberArray.length);
// display result 
 alert(thisMean);
 alert(thisFrequency); i have this code for mean and frequency how to find this for the values in databse. can you please help me thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't understand. You asked for pivot (or crosstab if you want) on your data. You have your answer as a ready to use resultset. So what is the problem?

Comment: am asking about mean and frequency calculation for db values

Comment: That's a totally different question, therefore you have to post it separately and other members of SO or I can try to help you.

Comment: can we dynamically build this crosstab